# python - creating bin labels from nparray

Tags: python, numpy

Having the following nparray describing my bin edges, created like so:

```
np.arange(min_value , max_value + 1, bin_size)

[ -1  35  71 107 143 179 215 251 287 323 359]
```

I would like to create string lables array like so:

```
['0-36','36-72','72-108','108-144','144-180','180-216','216-252','252-288','288-324','324-360']
```

What would be the way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
b = [f'{i+1}-{j+1}' for i, j in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])] 
print (b)
['0-36', '36-72', '72-108', '108-144', '144-180', 
 '180-216', '216-252', '252-288', '288-324', '324-360']
```

---

```
a += 1
b = [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])]
```